# How can i display the result of a method in a new view?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I have created an app which starts with a login page, after entering some user information I send a GET to server. Using the response values I create buttons, their title etc dynamically. Everything is ok, but after I send GET and use the JSON response my buttons are being created on the same view with the login page. I want to also create a new view and create buttons on that view. Since I use some parameters from user information I need to create the view in the same class with my MainViewController (in my case it is `BNT_1ViewController`) but I can't figure out how to handle this situation. I'm sharing the code too, maybe it helps.
And a second question, with this code my buttons just move downwards but I want two lines of buttons. How can I change the position of a button in the x axis? I changed those values but the whole column changes, even though I want just to place two buttons in the same line, all the struct replaces..

```
   -(IBAction)Accept:(id)sender
    {   userName=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:userNameField.text ];
        [userNameField setText:userName];
        NSUserDefaults *userNameDef= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userNameDef setObject:userName forKey:@"userNameKey"];
        password =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:passwordField.text];
        [passwordField setText:password];
        NSUserDefaults *passDef=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [passDef setObject:password forKey:@"passwordKey"];
       serverIP=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: serverField.text];
        [serverField setText:serverIP];
        NSUserDefaults *serverDef=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [serverDef setObject:serverIP forKey:@"serverIPKey"];
        [userNameDef synchronize];
        [serverDef synchronize];
        [passDef synchronize];
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BNTPRO "
                                                          message:@"Your User Informations are going to be sent to server. Do you accept?"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",  nil];
        [message show];
        }
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {


     NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
         if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
        {
             if([userNameField.text isEqualToString:@"" ]|| [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [serverField.text length]<10) 
            {
                UIAlertView *message1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BNTPRO "
                                                                   message:@"Your User Informations are not defined properly!"
                                                                  delegate:nil
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:  nil];
                [message1 show];
                [userNameField  resignFirstResponder];
                [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
                            return;
            }
            //## GET code to here**
            NSString *str1=[@"?username=" stringByAppendingString:userNameField.text];
            NSString *str2=[@"&password=" stringByAppendingString:passwordField.text];
            NSString *str3=[str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
            NSString *str4 =[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];
      NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[str4 stringByAppendingString:[@"/ipad/login.php" stringByAppendingString:str3]]];
        NSLog(@"%@\n",url);
        //get the url to jsondata
        NSData *jSonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (jSonData!=nil) {
            NSError *error=nil;
            id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jSonData options:
                       NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (error==nil) {
               NSDictionary *mess=[result objectForKey:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messContent=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messDate=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"date"];
                NSDictionary *messID=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
                NSLog(@"%@ *** Message %@ \n Message Content: %@ \n Mesage ID: %@ \n Message Date: %@", result, mess, messContent, messID,messDate);
                NSString*key1=[ result objectForKey:@"key" ];
                NSString *s1=[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];
                NSString *s2=[s1 stringByAppendingString:@"/ipad/button.php"];
                NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:[s2 stringByAppendingString:[@"?key=" stringByAppendingString:key1]]];
                NSLog(@"\n%@\n",url2 );
                NSData *data2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
                id result2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                //i create buttons from here
                 self.buttons = [NSMutableArray array];
                CGFloat yPosition = 43.0f;//measure from top point
                CGFloat xPosition = 34.0f;
                const CGFloat buttonHeight = 70.0f;//height
                 const CGFloat buttonMargin = 32.0f;//distance between two buttons

                for(NSDictionary* buttonData in result2) {

                    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                NSString* buttonTitle = [buttonData objectForKey:@"name"];
          [button addTarget:self action:@selector(secondAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                 [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];

                [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

              //      button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, yPosition, 130.0f, buttonHeight);//if([count]%2==1)
                     NSLog(@"Ne oluyor?= %d",[buttonData count]);

                 button.frame = CGRectMake(170.0f, yPosition, 130.0f, buttonHeight);//if([count]%2==1)



                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(secondAct:)                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [self.view addSubview:button];
                [self.buttons addObject:button];
                yPosition+= buttonHeight + buttonMargin;
    }        }
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
{
    NSLog(@"You changed your mind!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following are answers of your queries, might be it will help you-
 1. I want to also be creating a new view and create buttons on that view.
for this you can create a new view controller and push that view controller once you received the response. Also you can float the response from one controller to other.
2. And a second question, with this code my buttons just move downwards but i want two lines of buttons
You need to set frames of buttons properly, then will work perfectly.

Comment: Firstly thanks for this guidelines, but as i had pointed to in the first sentence of my question i'm not so knowledgeble in Objective C, can you shortly say which classes ect i have to use? or maybe any link to a related question-tutorial would be great.. Thanks again

Comment: You can google for this, a lot of tutorials are present there.Like one is - http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/navigationcontroller-application-in-iphone/